# CSS Content Property after element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this:

```
<div class="block3">
  <div class="surround">
    <div class="s_title">
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="block_content">
      <div class="content"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my example I can't add content directly in *HTML* (blocks rendered by default in *PHP*), so I need to add in *CSS*.

The hard part of this is that I need to add text **only** in `block3` element, after `<h3>` (`.s_title:after` will affect all `s_title`, so it will not work for me.)

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `.block3` in front of your selector like how you would limit selection of any other element to some container element:

```
.block3 .s_title:after
```